# How to display certain lines in a data record using Perl regular expression?

Tags: perl

I have the following data record format and would like to format it differently.

Original data record using the @ symbol

```
@dldldldld
dldldldldldl
windows
dfjldfldkldsjfl
difkjdljfdlsfld
fdlsjfdlskfdlsfd
```

and would like to output to be removing the @ symbol....

```
dldldldld                windows
                         dfjldfldkldsjfl
                         difkjdljfdlsfld
                         fdlsjfdlskfdlsfd
```

Here's the code I started but can't get it to work...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;


open 'FH','<',"/reformat.txt" or die "Unable to open file !";


$/='\@.*';

   while(<FH>)
   {               
      $_ =~ s/(.*?)(^windows[^\n]*)(.*)/$2$3/ms;
       print;
   }
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you just want to remove the `@` symbol? Or do you want to remove the `@` symbol, don't print the line after the line that has the `@` symbol, and then print following lines offset by `N` characters, making sure that the third line is actually printed on the same line as the line with the `@` symbol?

Answer (score 2):

```
open my $fh,'<', "/reformat.txt" or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    print if s/@// or /^windows/ .. 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks Wooble, thats part of the answer, the other part is I only want certain lines... I want the @slslsls line and all lines including the window line and all line beyond it.

Comment: Correct, print the @ symbol line but remove the @ symbol, and also, only print the lines including the windows line and beyond. Any lines below the @ symbol up to the windows line should be removed.

Comment: @brue walker: see the update.

Comment: that's not it, never mind, we can delete this question